# How to get your data from a select statement in Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

If I have this code (which is from their docs)

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user');
$query->param(':user', 'john');
$query->execute();
```

How would I access the actual data returned from this?

I am looking for an associate array containing `$array['username']` and whatever other columns are on the `users` table.

I have tried:

```
#1
echo $query->execute();
#2
$row = $query->execute();
echo $row['username'];
#3
$query->fetch();
```

None of which work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Database_Result` object is a wrapper for database row list. Usually it is used with foreach:

```
$rows = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user')
   ->param(':user', 'john')->execute();
foreach($rows as $row)
   echo $row['id'].': '.$row['username'];
```

If you are expecting only one row (its your question as I understand), use `current()`:

```
$row = current($rows);
echo $row['username'];
```

Note that `Database_Result` can be used as a simple array, so `current()`, `foreach()`, `count()` and other array functions are available.

PS. Here is a [link](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/query) for kohana 2.3 docs, using DB Queries is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's giving back a `Kohana_Database_Result` object. Try:

```
$rows = $result->as_array();
```

on it.

http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Database_Result

http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=crud_with_the_query_builder#reading_database_records

Answer (score 0):

Having never worked in the Kohana database part and given the Documentation is lacking examples for that (From what I could find). I have found a [Database_Query](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Database_Query) page. Which seems to be something like `$query->as_assoc()` here is how I would think it would be used, but not guaranteeing it will work.

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user');
$query->param(':user', 'john');
$query->as_assoc();
$return = $query->execute();
```

Just from the limited information I found that will hopefully work.